# Parágrafo html não "quebra" e o conteúdo fica escondido

Tags: php, html, css

Insiro vários comentários que são recebidos do banco com o código abaixo:

```
    $retorno = '<ul>';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){

        $retorno .= '
            <li id="comentario-resposta-'.$_POST['id'].'" class="comentario-resposta">
                <button class="btn btn-link">'.$row['nome_login'].'</button>
                <p>'.$row['comentario'].'</p>
            </li>
        ';
    }

    $retorno .= "</ul>";
```

css

```
.comentario-resposta p{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Essa imagem mostra o problema, tenho um modal onde ficam os comentários, percebam que há dois ficam com parte escondido e não quebram a linha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente utilizar nessa classe: [`word-wrap: break-word`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)?

Comment: Não post imagens! Veja porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: @Leo Caracciolo ele não postou imagem de código impossibilitando a ajuda, mas sim do problema, dessa forma creio que não haja problema.

Comment: @AdrianoBack, tudo bem mas para fazermos testes teríamos que criar o HTML do modal, mas felizmente surgiu um fera que resolveu sem necessidade de realizar teste!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que há em comum nos dois comentários, que há somente 1 palavra com muitos caracteres que ultrapassam o limite da div, por isso não quebra a linha... mas se mesmo assim quiser quebrar a palavra no limite da div utilize no css:

```
.comentario-resposta p{
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 50%;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

}